# Save and test AWS Lambda Functions

Tags: aws-lambda

Is there a way to save & test an AWS Lambda function with a single click? Ideally, I'd like to be able to test unsaved changes but I don't see an option for this. I'm just finding it tedious to save each time I want to test out changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your Lambda function via the AWS Lambda console, then you will need to **Save** the function before running **Test**. This is because the function runs on a Lambda container, not in the console.

Alternatively, you can run **Lambda Local** to test functions on your own computer rather than on the Lambda service. Once the code works, you can upload it to AWS.

See: [Run AWS Lambda Functions Locally on a Windows Machine - DZone Cloud](https://dzone.com/articles/run-aws-lambda-functions-locally-on-windows-machin)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any suggested place to ask for feature requests for AWS? It would be great if they added a single button that would test immediately after it was saved.

Comment: There is a Feedback button at the bottom of the AWS management console.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Endly](https://github.com/viant/endly/) automation runner with [aws/lambda](https://github.com/viant/endly/tree/master/system/cloud/aws/lambda) service

In this case, you would define your deployment workflow and just run it with

`endly deploy`

Where deploy.yaml defines automation workflow

```
init:
  functionRole: lambda-helloworld-executor
  functionName: HelloWorld
  codeZip: /tmp/hello/main.zip
  privilegePolicy: privilege-policy.json
pipeline:
  deploy:
    action: aws/lambda:deploy
    credentials: aws
    functionname: $functionName
    runtime:  go1.x
    handler: helloworld
    code:
      zipfile: $LoadBinary(${codeZip})
    rolename: lambda-helloworld-executor
    define:
      - policyname: my-bucket-role
        policydocument: $Cat('${privilegePolicy}')
    attach:
      - policyarn: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

Finally, you might be in end to end testing automation [here](https://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e/tree/master/lambda)